# Configure cmake VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am trying to configure cmake in VS code but I am encountering a weird issue.
I get the following error:

```
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -v
[proc] The command: ninja --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja ENOENT
[proc] The command: ninja-build --version failed with error: Error: spawn ninja-build 
ENOENT
[proc] The command: make --version failed with error: Error: spawn make ENOENT
[main] Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a 
preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable. 
Error: No usable generator found.
```

From what I understand, the configuration program cannot run cmake, nor ninja, nor ninja-build.
But cmake runs fine on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\JCG9900\Desktop>cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

The same for ninja:

```
C:\Users\JCG9900\Desktop>ninja --version
1.11.1
```

When I try to type the ninja-build command, I don't get anything. I don't know where is the problem, some threads mentions a compiler issue, but VS code finds my compiler directly and I don't see what could be wrong, any idea?

Comment: Show your configuration command. Did you specify `-G Ninja`? I'm just curious about why CMake is trying to find both Ninja and make. This looks like a VS Code thing and not a CMake thing. Did you put the directories containing those programs in your `PATH`?

Comment: What if you restart VS Code and try again?

Comment: I am using a command but the CMake tools in VS studio, I just click on the configure entry

Comment: are you using kits or presets? what generator did you select? Is there anything more in the CMake log that you're not showing?

Comment: I closed everything and restarted VS Code, and now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I closed everything and restarted VS Code, and now it is working fine